# Why has Carlsen's Elo not changed?

Tags: rating, world-championship, elo, carlsen

Just looking up Carlsen's Elo and it is still [2870](http://ratings.fide.com/card.phtml?event=1503014).

I know his next goal is to reach 2900. Did the 3 wins in the world chess championship simply not give him any rating points, or does FIDE take a long time to update ratings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does take awhile for [FIDE](http://www.fide.com/) to update their ratings, which is monthly ([see article](http://en.chessbase.com/post/fide-july-ratings-carlsen-at-a-record-2837)) compared to the unofficial Live ratings site at [Live Ratings](http://www.2700chess.com/). But it is interesting to note that Carlsen is due for a 2 point bump according to the Live rating site.

Answer (score 5):

With ELO (and most other chess rating systems I know of), it is difficult to substantially increase your rating when you play someone with a much lower rating. Also, whenever you draw against someone with a lower rating, that decreases your rating.

In the case of Carlsen's goal of 2900, where even the second highest rated player is 70 points below him, a draw is almost like a loss! And in a game where draws are very common at the top level, that makes Carles'n goal very ambitious. Still, if anyone can do it ...